Calculate user reputation for questions and answers that are not older than a year
I want to be able to compare the activity of StackOverflow users, but comparing two users with a year and ten years of experience by their reputation does not seem entirely indicative.
That's why I want to compare the reputation of users received only for questions and answers that are not older than 365 days.
Please help me compose a query that will return the user's reputation received for questions asked in the last 365 days and answers given in the last 365 days.

If you only need a rough approximation SEDE might be easier: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1880988?userid1=17547033&userid2=19170534

Hello @rene What is post? Is it question, answer or both?

@rene Is “v.creationdate” creation post or vote? I need creation of question or answer, not vote date.

Post is both quetstion and answers (posttypeid ==1 => Q, posttypeid ==2 => A). v.creatiodate is the date a vote was cast. If you need post dates you can replace it with p.creationdate

Via the Stack Exchange API:

Fetch all posts by the two users which were created in the last year with the help of the fromdate parameter. Note that user ids are semicolon separated.

Fetch the (public) reputation history of the two users, filter out the events regarding posts whose ids were not returned in the previous API call, and sum the reputation_change fields of all the remaining events.


Here's a Python implementation, which uses StackAPI:
from stackapi import StackAPI
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

year = (datetime.now() - relativedelta(years=1)).timestamp()

SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow', key = '') # add your key

# fill user ids
user1 = 0
user2 = 0

# fetch all posts by user1 and user2 in the last year
posts = SITE.fetch(
    'users/{ids}/posts',
    ids=[user1, user2],
    filter='!*Ju*n-1rscDl8QtK',
    fromdate=round(year)
)
ids = [item['post_id'] for item in posts['items']]

# fetch the reputation history of user1 and user2
history = SITE.fetch('users/{ids}/reputation-history', ids=[user1,user2])
total1 = sum(item['reputation_change'] for item in history['items'] if item['post_id'] in ids and item['user_id'] == user1)
total2 = sum(item['reputation_change'] for item in history['items'] if item['post_id'] in ids and item['user_id'] == user2)
print(total1)
print(total2)

Make sure to register your application in order to obtain a key.

Many thanks to @rene for his ideas in the comments to the question.
Here is the query that calculates the user's reputation for posts no older than 365 days.
select posts.owneruserid [User Link]
     , sum( case votes.votetypeid
            when 1 then 15
            when 2 then 10
            when 3 then -2
            else 0
            end
        ) [estimated rep.]
from posts
inner join votes on votes.postid = posts.id
where posts.creationdate > dateadd(dd, -365, getdate())
and posts.owneruserid = ##userId##
group by posts.owneruserid

